# MSSQL Field alias (AS) has stopped working

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache, odbc

We are trying to move a Linux machine with PHP 5.2.1 to a virtual machine with PHP 5.3.3. Using Apache web server.

All the scripts that have:

```
Select real_column as alias_column from some_table
```

return null for alias_column. 
If we remove the "as alias_column" everything works correctly.

We are using the LibTDS ODBC driver, connecting to MS-SQL 2008.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please give a full query as an example.  Both the SQL and the PHP that is not presenting the alias names?

Comment: Did you update the FreeTDS conf to the new SQL version? ´tds version=7.2´ for 2008. If that doesn't do the trick, have a look at creating a log and have a look ´dump file = /path/to/file´

Comment: Oh, just realised I had seen something like that before with the ODBC version. Have a look at: http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2010q2/025720.html

Answer (score 0):

`alias_column` should be surrounded by single quotes, ie:

```
SELECT real_column AS 'alias_column' FROM some_table
```

If you're still not getting any results you may want to look check if the statement is generating any error messages, which may also involve turning up the error_reporting level in PHP.

Also, try a `var_dump()` on your results to see if your results are still being returned in the expected format.

Comment: You only need to comment the alias column in SQL Server if you intend to use characters that are reserved for example : select col as 'my col' from table : select col as 'my-col' from table.  If you use alias_column quoting the alias name is not required.